# Best way to stream mp3

Tags: streaming, mp3, ogg, icecast

I need to organize mp3-streaming from my machine to the rest of the world. People advised me to use [MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) with [Icecast2](http://www.icecast.org/) as frontend. Everything is ok except one thing — music is being streamed as [Ogg Vorbis](http://xiph.org/vorbis/), not what actually I need.

There's a snippet of MPD's config file:

```
audio_output {
    type                    "shout"
    name                    "Radio"
    host                    "localhost"
    port                    "8000"
    encoding                "mp3"
    mount                   "/radio.ogg"
    password                "mypass"
    bitrate                 "256"
    format                  "44100:16:2"
    protocol                "icecast2"
    description             "radio stream"
}
```

But, Icecast's status page says it's streaming ogg, not mp3.
MPD's version is 0.13.2 running on Debian Lenny. What's wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I have LAME encoder compiled.

Comment: Hm, can you use winamp as a streaming encoder?  You didn't enter your platform constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my question is solved. I just compiled 0.15.2 version of MPD with --enable_shout and --enable_ffmpeg keys.